# jquery corners not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use jQuery Corners 0.3, but it doesn't work in any other version of IE besides IE9.  The error message is: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid property value.  This error happens in the jquery.corners.min.js file.  Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I have been using the corner (version 2.12) plugin found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/ and it works fine in IE 8.

Comment: @rontornambe Using corner solved my problem.  You should put your comment into an answer, so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: I appreciate the heads-up and am glad your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the corner (version 2.12) plugin found here: jquery.malsup.com/corner and it works fine in IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a DOCTYPE / Quirks mode issue to me. Try putting the browser into standards mode.

Or it could be that your browser is in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but I solved just setting the color of the border

```
$('#div').corner("5px sc:#75b4dd");
```